# Getting path of a file using C or Opencv

Tags: c, opencv

I need to load an image into my program. I want to allow the user to browse for any image s/he wishes and open. I need a function which asks the user to browse and select the desired file and can generate a string containing the complete path of that particular file.

Comment: i am using opencv for processing my images. if there is any function directly in opencv which can help, it will be better

Comment: User interface is in highgui module http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html

Comment: That's what I wanted to point out

Comment: you know many of the opencv functions are undocumented...

Comment: There are no functions on OpenCV to do that. What you are looking for is a GUI mechanism to allows the user to select a file from the disk. There are several libraries to do that depending on your OS. Check GTK+ and Qt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say on which platform you are working.

If you are working on Windows, the fastest way is to use the OPENFILENAME structure with the GetOpenFileName function as shown in this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646829(v=vs.85).aspx#open_file. You can then use cvLoadImage with the lpstrFile member of the structure.

On linux, I would recommend using Qt and the QFileDialog. Note that you can also use Qt on Windows.

Comment: can you tell how to use this lpstrFile with cvLoadImage? I am simply using cvLoadImage(ofn.lpstrFile,0). I found that ofn.lpstrFile contains the correct path of the file but cvLoadImage is not able to toad file using it. cvLoadImage works fine if i give the same file path as a string.

Comment: I guess the problem here is that file is already opened while trying to get its path. thats why i am getting null pointer when i use cvLoadImage.

Answer (score 0):

Use fltk, namely: http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#Fl_File_Browser